# Выгрузка только определенных типов из БД

Tags: php, база-данных

Есть цикл, который создает выгрузочный файл:

```
        $result_for_base_a = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM oc_order_option WHERE order_id = '$id'");
        for($j = 0; $j<count($result_for_base_a->rows); $j++) {
            $product_option_value_id=$result_for_base_a->rows[$j]['product_option_value_id'];
            $product_option_id=$result_for_base_a->rows[$j]['product_option_id'];

            $result_for_base_c = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM oc_product_option WHERE product_option_id = '$product_option_id'");
            $product_id=$result_for_base_c->row['product_id'];
            $result_for_base_b = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM oc_product_option_value WHERE product_option_value_id = '$product_option_value_id' AND product_id='$product_id'");
            $points = $result_for_base_b->row['points'];

            $price = $result_for_base_b->row['price'];
            $counts = $result_for_base_a->rows[$j]['quantity'];
```

Мне нужно добавить правило, которое будет создать выгрузочные данные только для тех опций, которые select. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В таблице есть 'type', там есть select, checkbox, radio, image и др., но мне нужно, чтобы в цикле все типы игнорировались кроме select.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, ограничить выборку в самом первом SQL-запросе:

```
$result_for_base_a = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM oc_order_option WHERE order_id = '$id' AND type IN ('select');");
```

**`IN`** на случай, если захотите еще добавить значения, учитываемые при выборке.